# oracle XML to Database table

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle11g

I have XML like this . I am unable to parse it into a table

```
  <REQMST>
  <ROW>
    <REQ_ID>668 </REQ_ID>    
      <RequestDetails>
      <REQ_DTL_ID>845</REQ_DTL_ID>
      <INTERFACE_REFNUM>1</INTERFACE_REFNUM>
      </RequestDetails>
      <RequestDetails>
      <REQ_DTL_ID>846</REQ_DTL_ID>
      <INTERFACE_REFNUM>2</INTERFACE_REFNUM>
       </RequestDetails>     
    </ROW>
</REQMST>
```

I am trying to parse it into table using

```
select *  
FROM XMLTABLE('/REQMST/ROW'  
         PASSING   
            xmltype('
           <REQMST>
  <ROW>
    <REQ_ID>668 </REQ_ID>    
      <RequestDetails>
      <REQ_DTL_ID>845</REQ_DTL_ID>
      <INTERFACE_REFNUM>1</INTERFACE_REFNUM>
      </RequestDetails>
      <RequestDetails>
      <REQ_DTL_ID>846</REQ_DTL_ID>
      <INTERFACE_REFNUM>2</INTERFACE_REFNUM>
       </RequestDetails>     
    </ROW>
</REQMST>')
         COLUMNS  
            --describe columns and path to them:  
            REQ_ID  varchar2(20)                 PATH './REQ_ID',
            REQ_DTL_ID  varchar2(20)           PATH './RequestDetails/REQ_DTL_ID',
            INTERFACE_REFNUM varchar2(20)      PATH './RequestDetails/INTERFACE_REFNUM'
     ) xmlt  
;
```

I am getting error `ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence`

it works if there is only one RequestDetails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go one more level down to get the details from `RequestDetails` tag using the same technique as parent.

Used column name `xml` to get the xml as xmltype column and then use xmltable on it to get the further details:

Try this:

```
select xmlt.req_id, x.REQ_DTL_ID, x.INTERFACE_REFNUM
FROM XMLTABLE('/REQMST/ROW'  
         PASSING   
            xmltype('
           <REQMST>
                <ROW>
                    <REQ_ID>668 </REQ_ID>    
                    <RequestDetails>
                        <REQ_DTL_ID>845</REQ_DTL_ID>
                        <INTERFACE_REFNUM>1</INTERFACE_REFNUM>
                    </RequestDetails>
                    <RequestDetails>
                        <REQ_DTL_ID>846</REQ_DTL_ID>
                        <INTERFACE_REFNUM>2</INTERFACE_REFNUM>
                    </RequestDetails>     
                </ROW>
            </REQMST>')
         COLUMNS  
            --describe columns and path to them:  
            REQ_ID  varchar2(20)                 PATH 'REQ_ID',
            xml  xmltype         PATH 'RequestDetails'
     ) xmlt,  xmltable('/RequestDetails'
        passing xmlt.xml
        columns
             REQ_DTL_ID  varchar2(20)           PATH 'REQ_DTL_ID',
            INTERFACE_REFNUM varchar2(20)      PATH 'INTERFACE_REFNUM'
     ) x;
```

Produces:

```
REQ_ID  REQ_DTL_ID  INTERFACE_REFNUM
668     845         1
668     846         2
```